# What are the requirements to make autocomplete work for Node / Web monorepos in JetBrains IDEs like WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, autocomplete, monorepo

**My project is an Nx monorepo with several applications from Nuxt 3 to plain Vite, and I'm using TypeScript for all frontend-related stuff together with Gradle / Java for the backend. So it's a mixture of Gradle modules and node modules**

That said, I'm also using the **IntelliJ** **Gradle**, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15101-nx-console-idea and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15000-nx-console-ui **plugins**

While I don't have any problems compilation-wise, I'm sporadically but constantly facing issue with **IntelliJ's autocomplete** feature for **local library module dependencies** and I'd like to figure out what is necessary to make it working once and for all.

For example, I'm trying to import a certain Vue component from my component library

> import { BaseHero } from "@my-workspace/ui";

IntelliJ complains with **Cannot resolve symbol "BaseHero"**

As I'm using TypeScript, my root **tsconfig.base.json** contains one entry for all library modules in the **paths** property and all **applications and libraries extend this config**.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@my-workspace/ui": [
        "components/ui/index.ts"
      ],
      "@my-workspace/demo-sdk": [
        "components/demo-sdk/index.ts"
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "tmp"
    ],
  }

}
```

I've read somewhere that these **paths entries are crucial for IntelliJ's autocompletion**, but the **current behavior contradicts this thesis** and also, **what if I don't use TypeScript and instead just vanilla JS** - wouldn't I be able to use autocompletion at all in this case?

Now my library module's package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "@my-workspace/demo-sdk",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./index.ts"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "types": "./components.d.ts"
}
```

Is the **main** and **types** entry crucial for IntelliJ's autocompletion feature as well? I'd guess so

**Another thought is, IntelliJ is just scanning the node_modules directory. However, although my local modules have a link in there as well, they aren't working with autocomplete, while external dependency modules are working.**

**Edit: The project works flawlessly in VSCode but not in IntelliJ - I guess the setup must be more or less correct.**

Also, after performing **repair** with IntelliJ's repair assist and **Invalidate Cache and Restart** afterwards **the issue still pesists**

[image: IntelliJ repair invalidate restart TypeScript autocomplete still not working]

**What requirements must be fulfilled to make autocomplete working in IntelliJ products for Node monorepos flawlessly?**

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens if you just remove the "types" field as you're already exporting the main.ts. Also with noEmit are the declarations being written at all? Finally, why have main as index.ts but the types as component.d.ts

Comment: Hi @cefn , first of all thanks for your response. I've removed the types field and so far nothing spectacular happens.. No, there aren't declarations written, I've done it manually before by building the lib each time a new component was added. With noEmit=false there still won't be a components.d.ts created in the library package. Honestly my base tsconfig is a mixture of settings out of all starter projects I've used and consolidated there. I do not understand what you mean by "why have main as index.ts but the types as component.d.ts" - could you please explain?

Comment: This is a bit of a black box for me too, but if you export a .ts file then it comes with all the types already. It makes more sense to my mind to have a types field if the main export is e.g. dist/index.js (and therefore doesn't have types). Additionally, it reduces the number of ways things can go wrong, otherwise there might be two locations attempting to influence your types at once, which is bound to be harder to trace.

Comment: Interesting, so I guess you only need it when you publish as CommonJS or so? Makes sense. The odd thing is, project has worked for several weeks now and the tsconfig.base.json has not really changed and the package.jsons are also the same. I have this issue in all applications that consume the libraries. Did several IntelliJ restarts with invalidate cache etc. I would understand this behavior if either the base config has changed, or if the problem would only occur with one app / library, but its a general issue it seems

Comment: @cefn so I've opened my project with VSCode now and the auto-completion works without any problems... damn. I don't know if it has anything to do with the IntelliJ module system, because it corrupts by itself all the time. My project is a mixture of Gradle and Web / Nx and maybe something interferes. But I've deleted the modules.xml and workspace.xml + the modules directory several times now to get the correct module structure and it did not change anything. I'm not finding anything suspicious when searching through the .idea dir, but I could imagine something is excluded somewhere from index

Comment: I must admit I gave up on using IntelliJ tools in favour of VSCode. I also gave up Nx in favour of wireit (which does much less, but does it well, and lets me correctly configure Typescript projects without having an opinion about it). Even in VSCode though, I occasionally need to restart the Typescript language server when I've made structural changes to an API (in VSCode there is a command for this without an IDE restart).

Comment: Good to know. I'm pretty happy with Nx for my purpose, can't complain so far after realizing that you don't rely on any plugins and generators etc. Just drop in a project.json into your module and you are fine :) I'll try to use vs code a bit until my idea decides to work again as magically as it stopped working or maybe sb else has a hint. I've also tried 3 different IDEA versions including the latest beta

Comment: @cefn btw has the TypeScript server to be running if you don't compile anything and just type things? I thought normally the IDE should understand the .ts files directly, no? Esp if you don't generate .d.ts files

Comment: The IDE has a background component running called the Typescript language server (an implementation shared by multiple IDEs). You don't need to launch it explicitly. But its cache sometimes gets confused if you are actually editing the files. Vscode has an action menu including a restart action.